Servicenow-CMDB Tables
Dean-> manager -> senior faculty -> junior faculty -> students
The above structure is in hierarchical form and when I open dean form in servicenow I should be able to see record i.e. rest of the staff under him. Similarly in manager I should be able to see below him.......and so on for junior faculty I will be able to see students and for students there should be no record
How to achieve this in service now ? please share valuable resources
can we do this using CMDB tables by creating dashboards ?? share your thoughts

Just add a Reference-type column/field of the 'upper level' table to the current table. Meaning, add a Reference to the Junior Faculty record in the Student table, then add a Reference to the Senior faculty record in the Junior Faculty table, and so on. Last will be the Reference field to the Dean record in the Manager table.
Then for each Form from Dean to Junior Faculty, add a Related List (ex. in Dean record form add related list Dean->Manager, in Manager record form add related list Manager->Senior Faculty.
